# default inactive state for ui-router-extras

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using [ui-router-extras](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras) to support parallel state for modal windows.  When an modal window is open, the "home" state become inactive, but is still visible in the background.  This allows me to have deep link for each modal windows.

However, I am having trouble figure out a good way to set the "default" inactive state to "home" if an user come through a modal window link.

I currently define my states like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',
    onEnter: function($modal) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'singup.html',
            size: 'large',
            controller: 'SignUpController'
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You only posted one state definition!
I tried to get the same working and finally figured it out. If you found a solution could you post it? If not please provide more details

Maybe my solution will help

```
angular.module('xbmcremoteApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider,$stickyStateProvider) {
        $stickyStateProvider.enableDebug(true);
        $stateProvider
            .state('movies', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/movies',
                templateUrl: 'app/movies/movies.html',
                controller: 'MoviesCtrl'
            }).state('movies.gallery', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'app/movies/movies-gallery/movies-gallery.html',
                controller: 'MoviesGalleryCtrl',
                sticky:true
            }).state('movies.gallery.details', {
                url: '/:id',
                onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function ($stateParams, $previousState, $modal, $resource) {
                    $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'app/movies/movies-gallery/myModalContent.html',
                        resolve: {
                            id: function () {
                                $stateParams.id
                            }
                        },
                        size:'lg',
                        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
                    }).result.then(function () {

                                return  $previousState.go("movies.gallery");

                        });
                }]
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check out ui-router-extras release 0.0.12 and above.  I've added support for default substates in DSR.  See this github issue for details:

https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/150

And read the updated API docs here: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/dsr

```
var myState = {
    name: 'foo',
    url: '/foo/:fooID/:barID',
    template: '<div></div>,
    controller: 'fooCtrl',
    deepStateRedirect: {
        default: { state: "foo.bar.baz.defaultSubState", params: { defaultStateParam1: "99" } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to transition to the substate while keeping the modal window open?

Comment: Nvm. I found it in the FAQ of sticky states. You're awesome :) Link here for others: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky