# ui-router-extras: DSR and parallel states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

If I understand [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284274/3997374) correctly, I should be able to use ui-router-extras’ deepstate-redirects to load a default template in the default ui-view when the first state loaded is a state that absolute-references a named ui-view.

Consider the following example:

```js
angular
.module( 'app', [ 'ui.router', 'ct.ui.router.extras' ])

.config( function ( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider

  .state( 'global', {
    template: '<div ui-view class="global"><em>empty global state</em></div>',
    deepStateRedirect: {
      default: { state: 'global.parent.child' }
    }
  })

  .state( 'global.parent', {
    template: '<div ui-view class="parent"><em>empty parent state</em></div>',
    sticky: true
  })

  .state( 'global.parent.child', {
    template: 'child view'
  })

  .state( 'global.dialog', {
    views: {
      'dialog@': { template: 'dialog view' }
    }
  });
})

.directive( 'body', function ( $state ) {
  return {
    link: function () {
      // this complies with global's DSR and goes straight to child-state:
      // $state.go( 'global' );

      // shouldn't this comply to global's DSR and show child-state as inactive state?
      $state.go( 'global.dialog' );
    }
  };
});
```

(plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fuFUFaqUGRjCKfajaWw2?p=preview)

Should the above work and am I missing something, or have I made some misassumptions here?

**My reasoning***:

* partially based on what I understood from previously mentioned post

When the `dialog` state is loaded, its parent-state (`global`) is also loaded. `global` has a deepstate-redirect to a state (`child`) that fills a ui-view that is not used by `dialog`, and as such, `child` its template is rendered in the default ui-view — or perhaps this would be a little too good to be true.